# How to generate $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ by the collection of all intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$ ？

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, measure-theory

How to generate $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$,the borel $\sigma$-algebra on $\mathbb{R}$, by the collection of all intervals of the form $(-\infty, x]$, where $ x \in \mathbb{Q}$？

Comment: You can write any open interval by taking complements and countable unions in the given collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}$, and choose $x_k$ to be a rational sequence increasing to $x$. Then $\cup (-\infty, x_k] = (-\infty, x)$. Since intervals of this form (usually called rays) generate the Borel sigma-algebra, you're done.